# Does MYSQL have table function?

Tags: mysql, db2

In DB2, I can use table function like

```
SELECT ELEMENTS
FROM  TABLE (AB_OWN.ELEMENTS (pv_token_id)) AS T
```

I'm wondering does MYSQL have similar function like this?
How could I translate it into MYSQL language?

Comment: For those not familiar with DB2, can you  explain what it returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [mysql8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) documentation, the `create function` statement does not currently support SQL standard table functions.

You will need an alternative approach, for example using a function or procedure to populate a table then selecting from that table, or some similar approach.